# Drupal 7 - activate php error log on prod

Tags: php, drupal-7, error-log

I would like to know how to activate php error log on prod ?

What I've already done:

```
 php.ini > error_log = [path to output file] + error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
 restart php.ini
 settings.php > error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

My error_log file still empty.
I really need it because I can't reproduce a bug outside from prod.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin/config/development/logging` and choose your settings

Comment: I do it too. Nothing changed.

Comment: Yes my server does not really log any messages, is it in the settings.php?